# How can I make a div grow the same size as another div, while keeping it's text vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two divs, or "panels".  One panel doesn't include an image, so it doesn't scale correctly with the panels that do have images.

Heres an example of what's going on.

http://www.bootply.com/TpbX2VOh0v

Could somebody help me make the bottom panel scale the same size as the top panel, while keeping the text centered horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Do you want the text in the bottom panel to be the full width of the DIV?

Comment: No, I wan't it centered in the div with padding around it.

Comment: When I look at your demo I see the text in the second DIV centered with padding. I am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @markbernard I want the div height to grow with the div height above it when the browser size changes.

Comment: Ok. I don't know how to do that without Javascript.

Comment: @markbernard What would be a Javascript solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Javascript you listen for resize events a react by making both DIVs the same height.

```
$("#panel-1").resize(function(event) {
    setSizes();
});
$("#panel-4").resize(function(event) {
    setSizes();
});

function setSizes() {
    var height1 = $("#panel-1").height(),
    var height2 = $("#panel-4").height(),
    var finalHeight = height1;

    if(finalHeight < height2) {
        finalHeight = height2;
    }

    if(height1 !== height2) {
        $("#panel-1").css("height", finalHeight);
        $("#panel-4").css("height", finalHeight);
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. You can do it without jQuery too. You just have to look up the raw Javascript calls.

Comment: Thanks, this function works.  I'm just having trouble getting .resize(); to call the function.

Comment: I ended up using `$( window ).resize(function(event) {
    setSizes();
});`  and that fixed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just don't assign height or width, just insert content and put the div inside the div.